# Wordpress + MAMP: always redirected to live site

Tags: wordpress, mamp

When I install a backup of my Wordpress site on my local MAMP server, so i can work on it and test new features etc, and I visit ANY link or do anything (including logging in) it always throws me to the actual live website.

For example, if the local address for the site is "localhost/xyz" and I type that in, it takes me to it but anything after that throws me to the actual live site.

So on "localhost/xyz", if I click on log-in or any page etc, I end up at http://www.xyz.com

This is being VERY problematic because I can't test any page or work on any page locally.

How can i go about fixing this?

Comment: what is your site root set as in your wordpress admin panel? what is the attribute of the href for the link?

Comment: i dont know 100% what u mean but, when i for example type in "localhost/xyz/wp-admin " it auto throws me to the wp-admin of the actual site. when i go to for example, localhost/xyz/wp-login.php" it takes me there but when i enter login details and hit enter or press the submit button, it throws me to the site already logged in...

Comment: can you check the source code and see what the url is of the link/button you are clicking?

Comment: Hi dave, how would i find thiS? i look in the wp-login.php and i see no url there, i mouse over it to see if theres a browse bar that appears with the addy its going to send you to, and nothing. Im a noob at this so dont kill me lol.

Comment: check the source code using your browser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go into your database (on MAMP) via phpmyadmin, and check the options table, make sure that the lines for `siteurl` and `home` are set to `http://localhost/` and not the live site url.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solution with this http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these two videos that I made on transferring a WordPress site to MAMP. I think they will help you.

Part 1:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xn-8OvwFdBY

Part 2:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIIJBdpRzjM

Hopefully they help. :)